Windows 11 PowerShell shows my network adapter as False even though it's enabled
I am running Windows 11 Home with an Intel Killer Wi-Fi 6E AX1690i network adapter.  Running PowerShell as an administrator, I have enabled the adapter, and in fact it is working properly.  I have also confirmed that it is enabled in my Device Manager.  However, when I run a list of network adapters and their values, its value keeps showing up as False.  I need this value to be set to True.
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_NetworkAdapter" | Format-List -Property Name,PhysicalAdapter,MacAddress
Name            : Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
PhysicalAdapter : False
MacAddress      :
Name            : Killer(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX1690i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (411NGW)
PhysicalAdapter : False
MacAddress      : C8:CB:9E:61:1B:33
I have tried the following:

Right-clicking on the adapter in Device Manager, selecting Disable Driver and then right-clicking and selecting Enable Driver

Uninstalling the adapter and reinstalling it (including all system restarts)

Enabling the adapter in PowerShell:  PS C:\Windows\system32> Enable-NetAdapter -Name "Wi-Fi" -Confirm:$false


Note that the status of the Intel adapter is Up
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-NetAdapter | format-table
Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed

Wi-Fi 2                   Killer(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX1690i 160MHz Wi...      17 Not Present                             0 bps
Wi-Fi 5                   Killer(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX1690i 160MHz Wi...      16 Disconnected CA-CB-9E-61-1B-33          0 bps
Bluetooth Network Conn... Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Netw...      15 Disconnected C8-CB-9E-61-1B-37         3 Mbps
Wi-Fi 4                   Killer(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX1690i 160MHz Wi...       9 Disconnected C8-CB-9E-61-1B-34          0 bps
Wi-Fi 3                   Killer(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX1690i 160MHz Wi...       7 Disconnected C8-CB-9E-61-1B-35          0 bps
Wi-Fi                     Killer(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX1690i 160MHz Wi...       5 Up           C8-CB-9E-61-1B-33       817 Mbps
What am I missing?
Thanks.

Please format your post properly.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapter - "PhysicalAdapter - Indicates whether the adapter is a physical or a logical adapter. If True, the adapter is physical.". Enabling or disabling an adapter doesn't change it's status as a physical adapter or not - you probably want the "NetEnabled" property which says this on the same page... "Indicates whether the adapter is enabled or not. If True, the adapter is enabled."

I am experiencing this issue as well I believe it is a defect in the Killer Wi-fi Network Adapter.
For those commenting, this persons issue is not whether or not the adapter is enabled. OP said it is. The problem is that Windows incorrectly reports it as a virtual adapter, but it is a physical one. The poster needs windows to see it correctly.
